# How can I apply different styles to text in one table cell using docx module of python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

I use docx module and I have a simple table with dates in cells. I need to mark each date the way like you see on the pic:

[image]

So I know I could apply style to the whole cell. But is there any way to color text lines separately? Maybe xml?